# Receiving parcel in Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, mail

I would like to bring a musical instrument from my country to a Japanese friend via international postal parcel service. However, I would like to know about customs security in Japan. I mean to say is it better to give his address rather than mine for a smooth process? Or is it better to get in my name and give to him later?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel.

Comment: Please suggest the right forum before closing.After searching through stack exchange I found this is the most appropriate one.

Comment: @Science123 I'm not aware of any SE site where this is on-topic. Posting a parcel is not travelling, so your question is off-topic, here -- sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a gift to him? Then send it to him declaring it as a gift.

Is it for you to use and bring back? Then send it to yourself c/o him at his address. Declare it on your customs form when you enter the country.

> John Traveller
>          C/o Taro Urashima
>           1-2-3 Yamaha-cho
>           Chiyoda-ku, Tokyo 123-456

Comment: It's for him as a gift. My brother going to send it via international parcel. Where to declare about it?at the parcel center of my country?

Comment: @Science123 yup, there’s a customs declaration form you have to fill at the post office. I’d declare it as:   Musical instrument (gift)